# Laravel - Usar Eloquent Insert Json con multiple nodo

Tags: laravel

Estoy trantando de insertar información mediante el uso de `::insert` en Laravel. Mi problema comienza cuando intento hacerlo con multiple nodo.

*Request:*

```
{
    "salario_inicial": 10000,
    "salario_final": 20000,
    "descripcion": "lorem...",
    "prestaciones": { //Error de insercción.
        "despensa": false,
        "gasolina": false,
    }
}
```

*Controller:*

```
$data = $request->json()->all(); //Obtener información
$insertar = ModelName::insert($data);
```

El error de insercción es claro, ya que no puedo insertar un array en una columna.
Intente manipular mi modelo usando `$casts`

*Model*

```
protected $casts = [
          'prestaciones' => 'array'
];
```

Lo cual tampoco me funciona.
Entiendo que la forma más facil de hacerlo es crear una nueva instacia e ir insertardo los datos de columna en columna, sin embargo, es un codigo reutilizable 100%;

Tal ves la unica forma seria manipular el Modelo, pero no se como deberia quedar para que acepte este nodo como parte de una columna.

**¿Alguien sabe de que forma puedo hacerlo?**

*Mi Tabla:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `$job_pref->prestaciones` tiene un solo campo? si es así, podrías sobreescribir `$job_pref->prestaciones = $job_pref->prestaciones->despensa`

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y mostrar cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Hola @Shaz el resultado esperado solamente es que me deje **insertar** como viene el Json de arriba. Saludos.

Comment: No deberías de tener problema en almancenar esa estructura, podrías intentar cambiar el tipo de dato de tu columna prestaciones por una de tipo json

Comment: Probaste con json_decode() ? Esto insertara como string tus valores, y cuando necesites volver a usarlos como objeto realiza un json_encode()

Comment: @RafaelM pero como lo haria desde el modelo, ya que el controlador no puedo modificarlo. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba modificando tu migración cambiando el tipo de dato de tu columna a tipo json

[column json](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

Podrías hacer esto en tu código

```
$data = $request->all();
$data['prestaciones'] = json_encode($data["prestaciones"]);
$insertar = ModelName::create($data);
```

Comment: Como dije es un codigo reutilizable por lo tanto debo no puedo manipular el contralador. ¿Hay forma de integrar algo similar desde el modelo, ya que me seria más útil?

Comment: no puedes manipular el controlador, pero si el modelo? un poco extraña la forma de "proteger" algo.

Answer (score 1):

TIP: Con control sobre diseño podes modelar distinto.

Una tabla PRESTACIONES:
con claves foraneas:

- empleado_id y
- tipo_prestacion_id

TABLA EMPLEADOS

- id
- salario_inicial
  ...

TABLA PRESTACIONES

- id
- empleado_id (clave foranea)
- tipo_prestacion_id (clave foranea)
  ...

TABLA TIPOS PRESTACION

- id
- denominacion
  ...

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [answer] para poder mejorar tus respuestas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: No entiendo esto cómo responde a la pregunta.

Comment: Quizas no responda la pregunta, pero si da una opción de poder almacenar las prestaciones en otra tabla. Ahora bien, quien pregunta, indica que no es lo que quiere.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el controlador lo vas a tener que tocar si o si. El problema es que [`insert()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts) es un método del Query Builder que inserta lo que le pases sin modificar nada, no ejecuta lo que tengas definido en el modelo para Eloquent.

La alternativa es usar [`create()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment) que también te permite pasar un array con los campos a guardar pero, al ser de Eloquent, si podes manipular la información antes de guardarla. La información la maniupulas con [`mutators`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator).

Estoy asumiendo que estás generando una entrada nueva, sino tendrías que usar [`fill()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment). Lee todo lo referido a [`Mass Assignment`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment).

---

**Controller:**

```
$data = $request->json()->all();
$insertar = ModelName::create($data);
```

**Model:**

```
// Campos que pueden ser cargados mediante Mass Assignment
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'salario_inicial',
    'salario_final',
    'descripcion',
    'prestaciones',
];

// Cada vez que se guarda el campo "prestaciones" lo pasamos por un "json_encode()"
public function setPrestacionesAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['prestaciones'] = json_encode($value);
}
```

---

De esta forma dejás un controlador genérico (reutilizable), y en cada modelo definís lo que haga falta.